# Zooming your webapplication on demand

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive

Im working on a very large asp.Net mvc application, that uses the full width of the screen to show thing. Already on a full HD screen, things are limited, and barely squishable.

When I want to make it mobile friendly there will simply be a different organization of data on the screen, no worries.
But for tablet sized devices I would like to make the site "zoomable". You know when you go to some websites, the entire thing is super small, and then you can zoom with your fingers, in and out.
I want that, but on purpose.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can't programmatically adjust the browser's zoom level. From the sound of your requirements, it sounds like you'd be better off designing a responsive layout which works on a full sized screen as well as tablet/handheld devices.

Comment: You can use css.

Comment: Using relative values like %, em, rem, ch, and the like you can change the root font-size, and that'll change everything else.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the default behavior (user can zoom via pinch and spread) and whatever you mean by "but on purpose"?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. the % sizes idea sounded good, i will look into that. using Media and bootstrap is what i want to avoid for tablet sizes. the point is to have the website be normal, but when viewed on a tablet, it should be viewed asif the whole thing has been zoomed out to fit the screen size. And then you can use the pinch function to zoom in to your liking. Its better because my site isnt any good if you dont have the same view experience as with a full hd sized screen. Does this make sence?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a little bit fuzzy, but it sounds to me like you're looking to set the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)